# Show error message if non numeric value entered

Tags: javascript

How to show error message to user if non-numeric values are entered in the text box.

The error message can be displayed below the text box something like enter the numbers only

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use an input of type "number"? You can't enter anything but numbers there.

Answer (score 2):

Just add some sort of output in your `if`. Like `alert` or even better, with a message near the input field. But this is up to you.

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    alert("only input numbers");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dom element to show the error and add a class to initially hide it. If any input is anything other than number remove the class from the element

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    document.getElementById("errorNumber").classList.remove('error-hide')
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("errorNumber").classList.add('error-hide')
  return true;
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.error-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeyup="isNumber(event)" />
<p id="errorNumber" class='error error-hide'>Please enter only number </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `span` element to display the messages inline in the page:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    var errorClass = document.querySelector('.error');
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        errorClass.style.display = 'block'; 
        return false;
    }
    errorClass.style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}
```

```css
.error{
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<span class='error' >Enter numbers only</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your are not considering digits when it's typed from keyboard's 'numpad'.
Following should work.

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || (charCode > 57 && charCode < 96) || charCode > 105)) {
    document.getElementById("errorNumber").classList.remove('error-hide')
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("errorNumber").classList.add('error-hide')
  return true;
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.error-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeyup="isNumber(event)" />
<p id="errorNumber" class='error error-hide'>Please enter only number </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
    if(isNaN(evt.key)) {
        document.getElementById('inptErr').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('inptErr').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" onkeypress="isNumber(event)" />
<span id="inptErr" style="display:none;color:red;">Please enter numbers only</span>
```